# Accessing Current Tab DOM Object from "popup.html"?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm developing an extension for Google Chrome browser.
I could not figure out how to access the current tab DOM object from the "popup.html" page. 
any suggestions?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

By default, within popup.js/popup.html, the "document" object refers to the extension's popup window's document only.  To get the DOM for a specific tab (for instance the currently active tab), you would need to use [content scripts communications](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html). For example we need to send a request from the [extension](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-sendRequest) to your content script via [popup](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html), so in the popup.html you do something like this:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
  // Send a request to the content script.
  chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {action: "getDOM"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.dom);
  });
});
```

Now in the content script, we need to [listen for those events](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#event-onRequest) coming from the extension, so in some file we named dom.js

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
 if (request.action == "getDOM")
   sendResponse({dom: "The dom that you want to get"});
 else
   sendResponse({}); // Send nothing..
});
```

Now remember to setup your [manifest](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html) to include the content script and tab permission.

Comment: Yes, what I showed you in my example is synchronous messaging done in Chrome Extensions. I returned a String "The dom that you want to get", but in reality, you can return any DOM you want. If you want to get everything in body you can do "sendResponse({dom: document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]});"

Comment: does the above example work? AFAIK send response will serialize the dom as json which is likely to result in an error due to the circular structure of the dom object.

Comment: Peter, Correct,so you would need to pass it in a format that is transferable.

Comment: it seems weird for this answer to have gotten such high up votes, considering that DOM objects are not serializable. It's true that you can serialize the actual html but that's not what the OP asked for. As far as I know, you can't access DOM objects from the background/popup script. You have to inject a content script to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: [**`chrome.tabs.getSelected` Deprecated since Chrome 33**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getSelected); [**`chrome.tabs.sendRequest` Deprecated since Chrome 33**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendRequest); [**`chrome.extension.onRequest` Deprecated since Chrome 33**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#event-onRequest).

Answer (score 9):

This is the latest fix:

popup.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
      console.log(response.farewell);
  });
});
```

(Note: the above console.log(response.farewell) is for popup.html, not your current tab)

contentscript.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
  });
```

Source: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

Answer (score 4):

This answer seems to not be working with the latest API. This is a working example.

popup.js:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    var tab = tabs[0];
    console.log(tab.url, tab.title);
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(msg) {
            msg = msg || {};
            console.log('onResponse', msg.farewell);
        });
    });
});
```

getDescription.js:

```
window.onload = function() {
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, _, sendResponse) {
        console.log('onMessage', msg);
        if (msg.greeting == "hello") {
            sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
        } else{
           sendResponse({});
        }
    });
};
```

relevant parts of manifest.json:

```
{
  "permissions": [
      "tabs"
  ],

  "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js": ["getDescription.js"]
    }
   ]
}
```