# Accessing Current Tab DOM Object from a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript

I have been searching around on how to accomplish this. I have found some articles most notably

[Accessing Current Tab DOM Object from "popup.html"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964225/accessing-current-tab-dom-object-from-popup-html)

However I am very new to JavaScript and making chrome extensions and I have hit a dead end.
My guess is that the response isn't being received which explains why `document.write("Hellp")`
isn't working. Any help to fix this up would be appreciated.

I have three main files

manifest.json

```
{
 "name": "My First Extension",
 "version": "1.0",
 "description": "The first extension that I made.",
 "browser_action": 
 {
  "default_icon": "icon.png",
  "popup": "popup.html"
 },
 "permissions":
 [
  "tabs"
 ],
 "content_scripts": 
 [{
  "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
  "js": ["dom.js"]
 }]
}
```

popup.html

```
<html>     
 <body>     
 </body>    
 <script>

 chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab)
 {
  // Send a request to the content script.
  chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {action: "getDOM"}, function(response)
  {
   document.write("Hello");
   document.write(response.title)
  });
 });

 </script>
</html>
```

dom.js

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) 
{
 if (request.action == "getDOM")
  sendResponse({dom: document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]});
 else
  sendResponse({}); // Send nothing..
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I see this is an older question, but it's unanswered and I ran into the same issue.  Maybe it's a security feature, but you don't seem to be able to return a DOM object.  You can, however, return text.  So for dom.js:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
 if (request.action == "getDOM")
   sendResponse({dom: document.body.innerHTML});
 else
   sendResponse({}); // Send nothing..
});
```

Comment: Actually, DOM objects cannot be sent because they are [not JSON-serializable](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple).

Comment: So how can we get DOM elements to the popup? @GaurangTandon

Comment: @Despertaweb Been an year since I've written that and I've honestly forgotten that part of my project. Well, I think I'd managed by either using a background page or sending the innerHTML across, and using some sort of global flags to coordinate b/w content scripts and background page. 

Sorry for being so uninformative!

Comment: @GaurangTandon not a prob. It's been solved by myself a "few" hours later! Thanx anyway   :D

Comment: @Despertaweb Now I am interested in knowing the soln. :P Do you mind posting it as an answer?

Comment: @GaurangTandon you got it :D

Comment: @Blair Please mark it as prefered solution if it suits to you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm workin on an extension that transfers the html of the element as a text and then rebuilding the element back using innerHTML. 
Hope that clarifies how to get the DOM  elements from the current page**

**This is the way I've got the DOM:**

**Manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version" : "2.0",
    "name": "Prettify search",
    "description": "This extension shows a search result from the current page",
  "icons":{
    "128": "./img/icon128.png",
    "48": "./img/icon48.png",
    "16": "./img/icon16.png"
  },
 "page_action": {
    "default_icon": "./img/icon16.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Prettify Results!"
  },

// If the context is the Mach url = sends a message to eventPage.js: active icon
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.whatever.cat/*"],
      "js": ["./js/content.js", "./js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"]
    }
  ],

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://www.whatever.cat/*",
    "http://loripsum.net/*"  //If you need to call and API here it goes
  ],

  "background":{
    "scripts": ["./js/eventPage.js"],
    "persistent": false
  }

}
```

**Popup.js**

```
    $(function() {
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {

            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action: "getPage"}, function(response) {

                var importedCode = response.searchResults;
                var fakeHtml = document.createElement( 'html' );
                fakeHtml.innerHTML = importedCode; // recieved String becomes html


          });
        });
```

**Eventpage.js**

```
>Able/disable the extension button 
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(req, sender, resp) {
    if(req.todo === 'showPageAction'){

        chrome.tabs.query({active:true, currentWindow:true}, function(tabs) {
            chrome.pageAction.show(tabs[0].id);
        });
    }
});
```

**content.js**

> Content_Scripts can not use the Chrome API to enable or disable the >extension icon. We pass a message to Event_Page, js, he can indeed
>   use the Api

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ todo: "showPageAction"});
window.onload = function() {

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.action == "getPage"){
        sendResponse({searchResults: document.body.innerHTML});
      }
  });  
};
```

**popup.html**

> Just link popup.js

Comment: Might be helpful to summarize by saying that you're transferring the html of the element as a text and then rebuilding the element back using innerHTML.