# Getting Value of Scroll Not Outputting

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom

Why is the value of scroll outputting as undefined?  I'm making an extension with chrome.

```
var scroll = document.body.scrollTop;
console.log(scroll);
```

Comment: Maybe that will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374793/accessing-current-tab-dom-object-from-a-chrome-extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

W3C Documentation is at:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrolltop.asp

From the documentation:

```
var body = document.body; // Safari
var html = document.documentElement; 
    // Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera places the overflow at 
    // the <html> level, unless else is specified. Therefore, 
    // we use the documentElement property for these browsers
body.scrollLeft += 30;
body.scrollTop += 10;
html.scrollLeft += 30;
html.scrollTop += 10;
```