# accessing the current html page from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to chrome extensions.
I would like to create a simple chrome extension that popup an alert with the title of the current html page. 
when I'm performing: `alert(document.title)` , I'm not getting it because the document object doesn't belong to the page but to the extension script (is it correct?)
how do i get the right document object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [tabs module](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html):

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab) {
    alert(tab.title);
});
```

Answer (score 20):

Content scripts are the easiest way to go:

Expand your manifest file with this code:

```
...
"content_scripts": [
  {
  "matches": ["http://urlhere/*"],
  "js": ["contentscript.js"]
  }
],
...
```

Content script (automatically executed on each page as mentioned at `matches` at the manifest file):

```
alert(document.title)
```

The advantage of using content scripts over `chrome.extension.*` methods is that your extension doesn't require scary permissions, such as `tabs`.

---

See also:

- [Developer's guide](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/devguide.html)
- [Content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html)
- [Background pages](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html)

Comment: @ Rob W: I just asked a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964225/accessing-current-tab-dom-object-from-popup-html. But in my case the extension is sending the information from the current tab to my bookmarking app. The way I understand your answer, then, any page I attempt to bookmark needs to be included in the manifest file. Is this correct? In which case, it will be useless. Thanks.

Comment: @Zeynel Then include `"*"`: `"matches": ["*"],`

Comment: @ Rob W: Thanks. I might not be doing this right but I had to enter  `"matches": ["http://*/*"],` to make it work according to this http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html otherwise I got `Missing scheme separator` I haven't tried it yet but at least the extension uploaded. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

For what you're doing all you need to do is this

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'alert(document.title)'
})
```

Chrome.tabs.executeScript allows you to run JavaScript in the current page instead of in the extension. So this works just fine but if you want to use the name of the page later in a more complex extension than I would just do what pimvdb did

Comment: Would this require to add `unsafe-eval` to CSP?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a function?

Comment: This was for Manifest V2 or lower. Tabs.executescript was removed in chrome version 91 https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/tabs#method-executeScript

Answer (score 1):

I use this extension to do a similar thing:

main.js:

```
(function(){window.prompt('Page title:', document.title)})()
```

manifest.json:

```
{
 "background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]},
 "browser_action": {
 "default_title": "popup_title"
 },
 "name": "popup_title",
 "description": "Display the page title for copying",
 "permissions": [
     "tabs",
     "http://*/*",
     "https://*/*"
 ],
 "version": "1.0",
 "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "main.js"})
});
```