# How to get the current tab's referrer from a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

From my chrome extension, I am trying to get the referrer link when a user
navigates to Amazon.com from another website but I am running into some issues.

I am using  [accessing the current html page from chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697001/accessing-the-current-)
html-page-from-chrome-extension?noredirect=1&lq=1 and
[Accessing Current Tab DOM Object from "popup.html"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964225/accessing-current-tab-dom-object-)
from-popup-html but still have issues.

My js in confirmation.js:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status == 'loading') {

          console.log(tab);

          console.log(document);
          //console.log(document.referrer);


  }
});
```

Currently, when this outputs the DOM of popup.html; not the current DOM of the tab the user is on. How do I get the document of the current tab the user is on?

Console.log(tab) provides the information for the current tab the user is on but I do not see any referrer attribute here.

Any advice on how I should solve this?

My manifest.json:

```
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "notifications"
],
"content_scripts": [
{
"matches": ["https://www.amazon.com/*"],
    "js": ["confirmation.js"]
}
]
```

Comment: To access web page DOM you need a content script.

Comment: @wOxxOm that was what I was attempting to do with the content script "confirmation.js" shown in the manifest. The code snippet above is from this file; is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: Ah, content scripts can't use chrome.tabs so you need an event/background page script for that, no need for a separate content script, just use content script literal code: chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {code: 'document.referrer', runAt: 'document_start', frameId: 0}, ([result]) => console.log(result))

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused. Do I put chrome.tabs.executeScript in the content script (confirmation.js according to the manifest above)? But it has chrome.tabs there and I thought you mentioned that content scripts can't use that?

Comment: the entire code I've mentioned goes into an event/background page script.

Comment: I get an error when I do this: Error in response to tabs.executeScript: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined
    at Object.chrome.tabs.executeScript [as callback]. I included the code you wrote all as one line in a background page script...should I be doing something else?

Comment: Well, use the standard ES5 syntax: `results => console.log(results[0])`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161860/discussion-between-sharataka-and-woxxom).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this...

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if(changeInfo.state === 'complete'){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
            code: "document.referrer;"
        },
        function(result) {
            // Here, you'll get the referrer
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: @KapilBarad I tried adding this code but I when I do console.log(result), I get undefined for a site that should have a referrer.