# Chrome Extension is not able to find button when using getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

When I load my Chrome extension it shows alerts properly but when I try to use getElementById() it is returning null.

I found this out by changing the first if statement to:

```
if (document.getElementById(button) == null) {
     alert("No element found");
}
```

It will print that but won't acknowledge anything besides null (such as "!= null"). The thing is, the element exists. I see it on the page when I inspect the page and I can interact with it but for some reason the Chrome Extension won't locate my button or any other element by id as far as I have tested, button or not.

Everywhere I look people say to make sure the Javascript runs after the page loads but I have set up the Extension to run when the DOM is fully loaded. I am at a complete loss here. I have spent hours working and researching this and cannot figure out what is going on.

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Clicker",
    "description": "Placeholder",
    "version": "0.1",

    // Permissions
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ],

    // Scripts
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["clicker.js"],
        "persistent": false
    }

}
```

clicker.js

```
window.onload = function (){
        var button = "clickIt";
    var run = 1;

    alert("Starting Clicker");

    while (run = 1){
        if (document.getElementById(button).disabled != true){
            document.getElementById(button).click();
                }
    }
}
```

testpage.html

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Clicker Test Page</title>

</head>


<body onload="timer()">
<button id="clickIt" type="button" disabled="true" onClick="addCount()">Test Button</button> </br></br></br>

<!--  display counter for test button clicks -->
<p>Counter: </p>
<span id="click_counter">0</span> </br>

<!-- display countdown timer for clock cycles -->
<p>Timer: </p>
<p id="display_timer"></p>
</body>

</html>

<script type="text/javascript">    
function timer(){
    var timeleft = 10;
    var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
        document.getElementById("display_timer").innerHTML = timeleft + " seconds remaining";
        timeleft -= 1;
        if(timeleft <= -1){
            clearInterval(downloadTimer);
            document.getElementById("clickIt").disabled = false;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

function addCount(){
    var val = document.getElementById("click_counter").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("click_counter").innerHTML = ++val;
    document.getElementById("clickIt").disabled = true;
    timer();
}
</script>
```

Test page works fine when played with manually. Although I am 100% sure the extension is working and looping infinitely as desired it cannot locate any elements by id and thus does absolutely nothing unless you put alerts in to see that it never enters the if statement. I also know it cannot find any of the other elements on the page.

Comment: You need to use a timer with `setInterval()` just like you have in the test page example. If you use an infinite `while` loop the script will just make the page lock up and the UI will never update.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [accessing the current html page from chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697001/accessing-the-current-html-page-from-chrome-extension)

Comment: The background script runs in a separate hidden background page. You need a content script here, see the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

wOxxOm was correct that I needed to make this a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) instead of a background script for it to be able to access the content (such as an element ID) in the DOM.

In addition, although Herohtar's comment was related to a different issue then the one I was addressing at the time of submitting this question it was an important factor later in the process of developing this extension:

Herohtar was correct that using a while loop overwhelmed the tab and caused the Chrome window to lock up and not respond because it was processing the clicks so quickly. Ultimately I fixed this by using a [mutation observer](https://www.javascripture.com/MutationObserver) with an inlay-ed [setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) function around the `button.click();` statement to stop the script from clicking too quickly.

Thank you both for your assistance.