# How to get a paragraph from the active tab with chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In my `background.html` I am getting the `id`, `url`, and `title` of the current tab like this:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
  tabId = tab.id;
  tabUrl = tab.url
  tabTitle = tab.title
  ...
```

I also need to get the first paragraph of the current tab. Is this possible? I don't see anything related in the [tab type](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#type-Tab). Thanks

**Update**

Update in response to [serg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733205/how-to-get-a-paragraph-from-the-active-tab-with-chrome-extension/7734388#7734388) and copying the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964225/accessing-current-tab-dom-object-from-popup-html/1964445#1964445):

This is `dom.js`:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
 if (request.action == "getDOM")
   //sendResponse({dom: "The dommmmm that you want to get"});
   sendResponse({dom: document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]});
   //sendResponse({dom: document.getElementsByTagName("p")});
 else
   sendResponse({}); // Send nothing..
});
```

and this is what I have in `background.html`:

```
  // Send a request to the content script.
  chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {action: "getDOM"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.dom);
  });
```

But nothing seems to be happenning. I don't even know where to look.

**Update**

```
manifest.json:

{
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "The first extension that I made.",
  "background_page": "background.html",
  "content_scripts": [
     {
       "matches": ["http://*/*"],
       "js": ["dom.js"]
     }
   ],  
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://ting-1.appspot.com/submithandlertest"
  ]
}
```

**Update**

Inserted console.logs for debugging but I see none of them in the console; in fact dom.js does not even running, I misspelled "else" as "els" and no error was given. But otherwise the extension works well and executes the xhr request. What am I doing wrong?

**dom.js**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
 if (request.action == "getDOM")
    console.log("dom.js - request action")
   sendResponse({dom: document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]});
   console.log("***dom.js - sendResponse***")
 else
   sendResponse({}); // Send nothing..
   console.log("***dom.js - else***")
});
```

**background.html**

```
<html>
<script>
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {

  // Send a request to the content script.
  chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {action: "getDOM"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.dom);
    console.log("background -- where is response.dom")
  });

    tabId = tab.id;
    console.log(tabId)
    tabUrl = tab.url
    console.log(tabUrl)
    tabTitle = tab.title
    console.log(tabTitle)

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("url", tabUrl);
formData.append("title", tabTitle);
formData.append("pitch", "this is a note");
//formData.append("user_tag_list", "tag1, tag2");


var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://ting-1.appspot.com/submithandlertest", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status == 200){ 
            console.log("request 200-OK");
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText ( { text: "done" } );
            setTimeout(function () {
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText( { text: "" } );
            }, 2000);
        }else{
            console.log("connection error");
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText ( { text: "ERR" } );
     }        
  }        
};
xhr.send(formData);
console.log("tabUrl: "+ tabUrl)
console.log(formData)

        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

**Edit**

Edited `background.html` as suggested by serg "to wrap all code that needs it into `chrome.tabs.sendRequest` callback (all those xhrs)". But this version of the background does not work. I don't get any error messages but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
    <script>
        chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) 
        {
            //chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) 
            //{
            // Send a request to the content script.
            chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {action: "getDOM"}, function(response) 
            {
                console.log(response.dom);
                console.log("background -- where is response.dom")
                //}); moving this down to include xhr
                tabId = tab.id;
                console.log(tabId)
                tabUrl = tab.url
                console.log(tabUrl)
                tabTitle = tab.title
                console.log(tabTitle)

                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append("url", tabUrl);
                formData.append("title", tabTitle);
                formData.append("pitch", "this is a note");
                //formData.append("user_tag_list", "tag1, tag2");

//xhr*********************************************************************************        
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("POST", "http://ting-1.appspot.com/submithandlertest", true);
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) 
                {
                    if (xhr.readyState == 4) 
                    {
                        if (xhr.status == 200)
                        { 
                            console.log("request 200-OK");
                            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText ( { text: "done" } );
                            setTimeout(function () 
                            {
                                chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText( { text: "" } );
                            }, 2000);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            console.log("connection error");
                            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText ( { text: "ERR" } );
                        }        
                    }        
                };
                xhr.send(formData);
                console.log("tabUrl: "+ tabUrl)
                console.log(formData)
//xhr**********************************************************************************                
            }); //chrome.tabs.sendRequest
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

**Update: Edited dom.js:**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener
(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) 
    {
        if (request.action == "getDOM")
        {
            console.log("dom.js - if (request.action == getDom)")
            //sendResponse({dom: "The dommmmm that you want to get"});
            //sendResponse({dom: document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]});

            sendResponse({dom: document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0]});
            console.log("***dom.js - sendResponse***")
            //var pageInfo = {
            //"title": document.title};
            //chrome.extension.sendRequest(pageInfo);
        }
        else
        {
            sendResponse({}); // Send nothing..
            console.log("***dom.js - else***")
        }
    }
);
```

**Update with latest background.html with the `console.log`s that are showing marked:**

```
<html>
<script>
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {

  // Send a request to the content script.
  chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {action: "getDOM"}, function(response) {
    //NOT SHOWING
    console.log(response.dom)
    //NOT SHOWING
    console.log("background -- where is response.dom")
  });

    tabId = tab.id;
    //SHOWING
    console.log(tabId)
    tabUrl = tab.url
    //SHOWING
    console.log(tabUrl)
    //SHOWING
    tabTitle = tab.title
    //SHOWING
    console.log(tabTitle)

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("url", tabUrl);
formData.append("title", tabTitle);
formData.append("pitch", "this is a note");
//formData.append("user_tag_list", "tag1, tag2");

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://ting-1.appspot.com/submithandlertest", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status == 200){
            //SHOWING 
            console.log("request 200-OK");
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText ( { text: "done" } );
            setTimeout(function () {
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText( { text: "" } );
            }, 2000);
        }else{
            //NOT SHOWING
            console.log("connection error");
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText ( { text: "ERR" } );
     }        
  }        
};
xhr.send(formData);
//SHOWING
console.log("tabUrl: "+ tabUrl)
//SHOWING
console.log(formData)

        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it from a background page, but you can inject [content script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/content_scripts.html) to all pages, and use [message passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/messaging.html) to pass this info back to background page on demand.

Comment: @ serg: Thanks. I updated the question with what I've been trying to do, but nothing is really happenning; I don't understand where the    `sendResponse({dom: document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]});` supposed to go. Can you explain how the info is passed back to the background page?

Comment: @Zeynel Your code looks good, can you show your manifest as well? Insert `console.log` into few places and see where it fails.

Comment: @ serg, ok, I'll try to debug. I added the manifest file to the question. Thanks.

Comment: @ serg, I added the console.logs but none of them are showing in the console. dom.js does not even executing.

Comment: @Zeynel Did you forget curly brackets in dom.js? Are you looking into the right console fro content script (it is regular tab console)? In background page you don't need to call `chrome.tabs.getSelected` as you already have selected tab from browserAction listener. Also if you are planning to use this returned dom inside background page, you need to wrap all code that needs it into `chrome.tabs.sendRequest` callback (all those xhrs).

Comment: @ serg, maybe I am not looking at the right console. I right-click on the extension icon and click on the `Inspect active views:
background.html`. Is there another console? And which curly brackets are missing in the dom.js? Thanks again!

Comment: @Zeynel Content script outputs into the same console as regular tab (Ctrl+J). You have `if..else` block without curly brackets. Also I just realized you are trying to pass whole dom element, it won't work as it is not serializable (contains circular references). You need to pass something that could be encoded into json. If you need first paragraph - get it in content script and pass result as string.

Comment: @ serg: I changed the background page to wrap xhrs in `chrome.tabs.sendRequest` but that code does not work, nothing happens. I updated the question with what I did. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Zeynel Problem is in dom.js - no curly brackets and you cannot pass dom element via request.

Comment: @ serg: sorry, I changed `dom.js` but forgot to add it to the question. Now the question is updated with `dom.js`. Do you think the way I have `background.html` is good? Thanks.

Comment: @Zeynel So did you see dom.js output in the console? You cannot pass whole dom element: `document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0]`, but you can pass: `document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML`

Comment: No, there are no console output from dom.js. I marked the console.logs showing and not showing in background.html and updated the question. The way I updated the background.html (wrapping the xhrs) is not working. I went back to how it was before.

Comment: @Zeynel Well first thing then is to get console output from dom.js, not necessary inside listener, anywhere. Add some output right into beginning of file and see if it shows. Remember to refresh page after installing extension.

Comment: @ serg: Thanks so much, finally I see the content of the first paragraph in the console. But there is no logs from dom.js but `console.log("background -- where is response.dom")` from background.html is now showing. Can you please also let me know how I can save the paragraph in background so that I can pass it to the app with xhr? I am still confused about where the returned item is. Thanks again.

Comment: @Zeynel I think you are still looking at the wrong console. Just open tab's regular console (hit ctrl+j on any tab), output from dom.js should be there. Once you found it check if there is no errors. To use returned value from dom.js in background page just use that `response.dom` inside callback function, like you did in the first edit (in your latest update you put xhr's outside of callback)

Comment: @ serg you were right I was looking at the console for the background. In my computer control j opens the downloads page; but I found it by right clicking on the page. For dom.js http://jsfiddle.net/4NDU5/ I only see the first console. You are also right that in order to get the response.dom I had to move the closing braces to the end http://jsfiddle.net/6v3B7/1/. Many thanks for your help with this.

Comment: @Zeynel Sorry I don't know what's the problem, everything looks ok. I would remove all the code and leave only absolute minimum required for sending request and receiving response to see if that works. Maybe some other code affects it.