# How to unchain chained anonymous functions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to unnest (or unchain) the chained anonymous functions below? I include my try after the script with nested anonymous functions. I want to define separately each function defined anonymously on its own to see clearly and understand where each function starts and ends and what they do. Thanks.

**A script with nested anonymous functions that I want to separate ([taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733205/how-to-get-a-paragraph-from-the-active-tab-with-chrome-extension)):**

```
<html>
<script>
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {

  chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {action: "getDOM"}, function(response) {
    var firstParagraph = response.dom;
  //}); moved to end to get the variable firstParagraph

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("url", tab.url);
formData.append("title", tab.title);
formData.append("pitch", firstParagraph);
//formData.append("user_tag_list", "tag1, tag2");


var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://ting-1.appspot.com/submithandlertest", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status == 200){ 
            console.log("request 200-OK");
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText ( { text: "done" } );
            setTimeout(function () {
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText( { text: "" } );
            }, 2000);
        }else{
            console.log("connection error");
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText ( { text: "ERR" } );
     }        
  }        
};
xhr.send(formData);


}); //chrome.tabs.sendRequest
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

**My try to unnest anonymous function and reconstruct the script:**

```
functionForSendRequest = function (response) {var firstParagraph = response.dom;
            var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append("url", tab.url);
                formData.append("title", tab.title);
                formData.append("pitch", firstParagraph);
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("POST", "http://ting-1.appspot.com/submithandlertest", true);
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4){
                    if (xhr.status == 200){ 
                        console.log("request 200-OK");
                        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: "done" });
                        setTimeout(function(){
                        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: ""});}, 2000);}
                    else{console.log("connection error");
                        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: "ERR"});}}};
                xhr.send(formData);}}

argumentToGetSelected = chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {action: "getDOM"}, functionForSendRequest()}

...

functionForGetSelected = function (tab) {chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {action: "getDOM"}, *function for getSelected goes here*)}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see the logic clearly, instead of "unchaining" them why not just try to practice good indentation. Then you can visually follow each method according to its indentation level. Like this:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {action: "getDOM"}, function(response) {
            var firstParagraph = response.dom;

            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("url", tab.url);
            formData.append("title", tab.title);
            formData.append("pitch", firstParagraph);
            //formData.append("user_tag_list", "tag1, tag2");

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "http://ting-1.appspot.com/submithandlertest", true);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                    if (xhr.status == 200){ 
                        console.log("request 200-OK");
                        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText ( { text: "done" } );
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText( { text: "" } );
                        }, 2000);
                    } else {
                        console.log("connection error");
                        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText ( { text: "ERR" } );
                    }        
                }        
            };
            xhr.send(formData);
        }); //chrome.tabs.sendRequest
    }); // chrome.tabs.getSelected
}); // chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener
```

Or, if you want to "unchain", the only really obvious thing to do is to define that inner callback separately, like this:

```
var handle_request = function(response) {
    var firstParagraph = response.dom;

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("url", tab.url);
    formData.append("title", tab.title);
    formData.append("pitch", firstParagraph);
    //formData.append("user_tag_list", "tag1, tag2");

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "http://ting-1.appspot.com/submithandlertest", true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200){ 
                console.log("request 200-OK");
                chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText ( { text: "done" } );
                setTimeout(function () {
                    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText( { text: "" } );
                }, 2000);
            } else {
                console.log("connection error");
                chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText ( { text: "ERR" } );
            }        
        }        
    };
    xhr.send(formData);
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {action: "getDOM"}, handle_requeest);
    });
});
```

Comment: You might also unchain the XHR response, so you have `handle_request` and `handle_response`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Does `var handle_request = function() {...}` need to have "response" as its argument?

Comment: You can write it as `function handle_request(response){...}`.

Comment: I tried something like this http://jsfiddle.net/9ECNn/ Is this valid? This way it is easier for me to see what each function does, but not sure if it is valid code. Thanks.

Comment: @RobG is right, both work, and they are good for different purposes. If you write it as RobG suggested, then it becomes a property of "window". In other words, writing "function x() {}" is similar (though not 100% equivalent) to writing "window.x = function() {}". Doing it the way I suggested, it is instead stored in a local variable. Both have purposes, but I tend to fall back to local variables if I don't have a specific reason not to. The encapsulationist in me makes me choose that default =).

Comment: @Ben - the way you have it, *handle_request* is created as a global variable before any code is executed, however it doesn't have a value until the statement on the right hand side is evaluated. Using a function declaration, it is assigned the value of the function before any code is executed. So using a function declaration you can call the function above where it is declared, but using assignment you can't call it until after the assignment.

Comment: @RobG and Ben Lee: Adapting your comments I tried to eliminate the chained anonymous functions by using function expression and function declaration: http://jsfiddle.net/9ECNn/1/ What do you think?

Comment: @RobG, yes I know how functions work. That's why I said they are similar "but not 100% equivalent". I just prefer the `var` method as a fallback for one-off callbacks if I don't have a reason to go with one or the other.

Comment: @RobG, I guess for me it's a semantic thing. If a function feels like a piece of logic separated out for re-usability or logical modularity, I tend to go with `function x() {}`. If it is separated out for one-off simplification, clarity, or callback purposes (like above) I tend to go with `var x = function() {}`

Comment: @Zeynel, the addListener stuff at the bottom is only 5 lines. I think it's actually far clearer with the logic not separated out into defined methods. I find the three-level nest much easier to understand than the way you rewrote it.

Comment: @Zeynel, but if you think it's easier to understand, it should work fine. Go with what makes sense to you.