# sending Message to content script on onClick event of Background page of Chrome's Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I know message passing is used for the purpose but somehow it is not working on onClick event of my background page. I am getting following exception:

```
Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at chrome-extension://aimjdbbnlgjodealdppjdpligkbjbmmb/background.js:27:31
    at disconnectListener (extensions::messaging:338:9)
    at Function.target.(anonymous function) (extensions::SafeBuiltins:19:14)
    at Event.dispatchToListener (extensions::event_bindings:386:22)
    at Event.dispatch_ (extensions::event_bindings:371:27)
    at Event.dispatch (extensions::event_bindings:392:17)
    at dispatchOnDisconnect (extensions::messaging:293:27)
```

Code given below:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name" : "My Ext",
    "description" : "XXX",
    "version" : "1.0",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
  ],
    "content_scripts" : [{
        "matches" : ["http://example.com/"],
        "js" : ["jquery.js","script.js"]
    }],
"background":{
  "scripts": ["jquery.js","background.js"]
},
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "XX"
      }
}
```

**dashboard.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="background.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <form>
      <textarea id="search"></textarea>
      <input id="button" type="button" value="Search" />
      </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Script.js**

```
var currentURL = document.location.href;
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#button").click(function()
    {
        alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
    });
});

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse)
{
    alert(msg);
    if (msg.method == "getHTML")
      sendResponse({data: "Welcome from Content Script"});
});
```

**background.js**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab){
  var loaderURL = chrome.extension.getURL("dashboard.html");
  _tab = activeTab;
  chrome.tabs.create({ url: loaderURL });
});
    $("#button").click(function()
    {
        chrome.extension.sendMessage({method: "getHTML",param:"myParam"}, function(response)
        {
                alert(response.data);
        });
    });

});
```

I can't use chrome.tabs.sendMessage because onClick event I am unable to find tab Id

Comment: I don't see any manifest or any info on how the above files are used (nor do I feel like guessing)...

Comment: @ExpertSystem pardon, it got skippd. Question updated

Comment: So where is `dashboard.html` used ?

Comment: it is  a background page. on clicking button, it loads dashboard.html which has a SEARCH button. upon clicking this it should send TEXTAREA content to content script

Comment: Sorry, I just took a closer look at `background.js`.

Comment: My approach might be wrong. All I want to send text area values to content script. Then those values will be used to parse data from DOM

Comment: I don't know if this is the root of the problem, but you are using the deprecated `chrome.extension.sendMessage/onMessage`. You should be using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage/onMessage` instead. Besides, it is a bad practice to use your `background.js` as script in another file (other than the background page). `dashboard.html` is **not** a background page, but a view (there is only up to one background page per extension - the one declared in manifest).

Comment: chrome.runtime always says undefined "data"

Comment: @ExpertSystem I try to implement your approach, may it work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758028/chrome-extension-get-dom-content

Comment: Good choice ! My solutions always work :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758028/chrome-extension-get-dom-content.

Comment: @ExpertSystem **chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { text: "report_back" },
                                doStuffWithDOM);** 
I can't pass tab.id in *$("#button").click(function()** method

Comment: @ExpertSystem getting **Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval ** on dashboard.html

Comment: What version of jquery are you using ?

Comment: 1.9. it's not issue of jquery

Comment: Are you using `eval` somewhere ? Could you post the actual code somewhere, so we can take a look ?

Comment: All of my code given in original question. Nothing left. I guess *script* tag in dashboard.html causing this issue. See above

Comment: The script tags as they appear in your question should not violate any policy, so something is different than in your question. Please, post the updated code.

Comment: @ExpertSystem this was the code I used while made a post. You may test it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to replace the deprecated `chrome.extension.onMessage` with **[`chrome.runtime.onMessage`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onMessage)** in `script.js`.

The main problem is that to **[send messages to content scripts](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#simple)** you need to use **[`chrome.tabs.sendMessage`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-sendMessage)** (which also requires to know the tab-ID).
An easy way to get this working, is to pass the tab-ID as a query parameter, when opening a `dashboard.html` view, e.g. `dashboard.html?tabId=XX` (see the modified `background.js` below).

**background.js:**

```
var queryStr = '?tabId=';
var loaderURL = chrome.extension.getURL('/popup/popup.html') + queryStr;
$(document).ready(function () {
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: loaderURL + tab.id });
    });

    if (location.search && (location.search.indexOf(queryStr) === 0)) {
        var tabID = parseInt(location.search.substring(queryStr.length));
        $('#button').click(function () {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabID, {
                method: 'getHTML',
                param:  'myParam'
            }, function (response) {
                if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                    alert('ERROR: ' + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
                } else {
                    alert(response.data);
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

---

As shown above, it is always a good idea to check for **[`chrome.runtime.lastError`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#property-lastError)** in chrome API callbacks to see if anything went wrong. In your case, you would see an error stating there is no receiving end, which would point to the right direction.

Comment: OK I test it. Do I need to make any changes at content_script end?

Comment: Just the changes I mention in my answer (i.e. use `chrome.runtime.onMessage` instead of `chrome.extension.onMessage`).

Comment: Thanks! it worked! but.. not sure i ask here or create another Question.. what if background.js is at receiving end? How do I accept data from content script on some buttin click event similar to one mentioned above?

Comment: The documentation is pretty clear on how to perform Message Passing (I suggest a closer look). For listening on bg-page use `chrome.runtime.onMessage`.

Comment: In that case, I suggest posting a new question with the relevant code (and problem description).

Comment: check please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20924782/receiving-message-from-chrome-extensions-content-script-to-background-js-file-o