# Receiving message from Chrome Extension's content script to background js file on button's Click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

My extension opens up an html page(dashboard.html) which contains a button. On click even of the button I want to receive message being sent by content script. Somehow I am not being able to do that. Code is given below

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name" : "My Ext",
    "description" : "XXX",
    "version" : "1.0",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
  ],
    "content_scripts" : [{
        "matches" : ["http://example.com/"],
        "js" : ["jquery.js","script.js"]
    }],
"background":{
  "scripts": ["jquery.js","background.js"]
},
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "XX"
      }
}
```

**dashboard.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="background.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <form>
      <textarea id="search"></textarea>
      <input id="button" type="button" value="Search" />
      </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Script.js**

```
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
  alert(response.farewell);
});
```

**background.js**

```
    var queryStr = '?tabId=';
var loaderURL = chrome.extension.getURL('dashboard.html') + queryStr;
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: loaderURL + tab.id });
    });
    if (location.search && (location.search.indexOf(queryStr) === 0))
    {
        var tabID = parseInt(location.search.substring(queryStr.length));
        alert(tabID);
        $('#button').click(function ()
        {
          /********following COde is not producing any result **/
            chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
              function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
                alert(sender.tab ?
                            "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                            "from the extension");
                alert(request.greeting);
                if (request.greeting == "hello")
                  sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
              });


        });

    }
});
```

Comment: I believe you are mixing things together. As stated in comments to your previous question, it is hardly a good practice to use a script (here `background.js`) both as a background page and as a JS script in a view (`dashboard.html`).In `background.js` you are registering a listener for the `onMessage` event in a button's `onclick` callback. This makes little sense (even less when considering that there is no button in your actual background page). The way you have it, a listener for the `onMessage` event will be registered only in `dashboard.html` every time you click the button.

Comment: So you suggest I add a separate background.html page for this purpose and in that I call script tag?

Comment: I suggest: 1. Add a different JS file (say `dashboard.js`) and replacing `background.js` with it in `dashboard.html`. 2. Remove any irrelevant code from `background.js` (i.e. everything below `location-search`). 3. Move the `onMessage` listener outside of the button's callback (place it as a top-level statement in the script).

Comment: Fine but how the msg received in background.js will then be used in dashboard.js and html file? how to pass there?

Comment: See my answer below ! (Essentialy, the message is received from `dashboard.js` directly - no need for `background.js` to be involved.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you need to send message from content script, since you can use `sendResponse` to pass back any necessary data, but...

---

**In *manifest.json*:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name":    "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",

    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches":    ["*://*/*"],
        "js":         ["jquery.min.js", "content.js"],
    }],

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Test Extension"
//        "default_icon": {
//            "19": "img/icon19.png",
//            "38": "img/icon38.png"
//        },
    },

}
```

---

**In *background.js*:**

```
var queryStr = '?tabId=';
var loaderURL = chrome.extension.getURL('dashboard.html') + queryStr;
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: loaderURL + tab.id });
});
```

---

**In *content.js*:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    alert('Message from a view:\n'
          + JSON.stringify(msg));

    if (msg.method === 'getHTML') {
        sendResponse({ data: 'Welcome from Content Script' });
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            body: 'Here I am, sending you another message !'
        });
    }
});
```

---

**In *dashboard.html*:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dashboard</title>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="dashboard.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <textarea id="search"></textarea><br />
            <input type="button" id="button" value="Search" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

**In *dashboard.js*:**

```
var queryStr = '?tabId=';

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender) {
    alert('Message from: Tab ' + sender.tab.id + ' (using `sendMessage`)\n'
          + JSON.stringify(msg));
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    if (location.search && (location.search.indexOf(queryStr) === 0)) {
        var tabID = parseInt(location.search.substring(queryStr.length));
        $('#button').click(function () {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabID, {
                method: 'getHTML',
                param:  'myParam'
            }, function (response) {
                if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                    alert('ERROR: ' + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
                } else {
                    alert('Message from: Tab ' + tabID
                          + ' (using `sendResponse`)\n'
                          + response.data);
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

---

One more thing:

- You don't need the `tabs` permission (at least for the presently shown functionality). It is a powerful permission, so don't use light-heartedly (for securty reasons and for not scaring users).

Comment: Simply marvelous. I got what blunder I had been doing. Thanks for your patience and help!! definitely great learning for me.