# Getting the html source code of the current web page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to create an extension for google chrome that can copy the html code of the current page and post it to a server ?

Comment: what have you investigated and tried so far?

Comment: I aim to scrap all images in a web page that need authentification. I've started by using an iframe to get the web page with the images, but i realised that getting the content of an iframe is impossible when the domain name is different. So i am now doing it manualy by coping the source code of the page after authentification and post it to my php script.

Comment: Now i had the idea that the dom content might be accessible by an extension, and this same extension might be able to post it (ajax) to my server, so i'm just asking people with experience if this is possible before starting to code.

Comment: And now i now that i can use the content script to access the dom elements of a web page, and i'm still reading...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Chrome Extension - Get DOM content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19758800/1814840) for an explanation using a content script, which has access to the DOM, and a background page to send and receive messages between. On the callback to `sendMessage`, you should be able to make an AJAX POST to the server with your data.