# Struggling to get DOM data in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have found several quite well up-voted questions here on Stack Overflow, though I can't actually find a working solution.

I've been trying to follow the answer here: [Chrome Extension - Get DOM content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758028/chrome-extension-get-dom-content), 
but I still get a completely blank console (despite reloading the extension)!

*manifest.json*:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "version": "0.0",
  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["https://*/*"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Test Extension",
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "permissions": ["activeTab"]
}
```

*background.js*:

```js
// A function to use as callback
function logDOM(domContent) {
    console.log('I received the following DOM content:\n' + domContent);
}

// When the browser-action button is clicked...
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    console.log(tab.url);
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {text: 'report_back'}, logDOM);

});
```

*content.js*:

```js
// Listen for messages
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    // If the received message has the expected format...
    if (msg.text === 'report_back') {
        // Call the specified callback, passing
        // the web-page's DOM content as argument
        sendResponse(document.all[0].outerHTML);
    }
});
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you in the background page console from chrome://extensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Remove `default_popup` from `browser_action`**:
The problem is that you are defining a `default_popup` for the `browser_action` in your *manifest.json*.  Change the `browser_action` to:

```
"browser_action": {
  "default_title": "Test Extension",
  "default_icon": "icon.png"
},
```

If you define a `default_popup`, then Chrome tries to display the popup and does not send a click event to your background script. You should have seen a popup displayed saying that your file was not found.

**Only injecting into `https` scheme pages:**
Given that you are only injecting your content script into `https://` pages, make sure you are testing on a page that is using the `https` scheme.

You may find it easier to test by injecting your content script into all URLs. You can do so by changing the `content_script` key in your *manifest.json* to:

```
"content_scripts": [{
  "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
  "js": ["content.js"]
}],
```

It is also not injected into pages in the `chrome` scheme (e.g. `chrome://extensions/`) (even when using `<all_urls>`). Thus, your extension will not work on those pages.

**You must load content page after loading the extension:**
You will also need to make sure you have reloaded the page, opened a new tab, or navigated to a new page after loading, or reloading, the extension. Your content script is not injected into already loaded pages.

**The Output is in the console for your background page:**
In addition, you will need to be looking at the [console for your background page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38920982/3773011). There are multiple consoles which you might need to be looking at depending on in which context/scope you are calling `console.log()`. The answer linked in the first sentence of this section describes how to view them.

***manifest.json* with all mentioned changes:**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "version": "0.0",
  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Test Extension",
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },

  "permissions": ["activeTab"]
}
```

Comment: thanks so much! I think the issue was me not looking at the console on my background page. Completely didn't think to look there oops!

Thanks for your explanation in all other areas too.