# Getting DOM access of a popup created with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a Chrome Extension that opens a popup with simple HTML. I'm not being able to access this popup DOM.

Is it possible to manipulate the popup DOM?

Examples:

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

  chrome.windows.create({"url": "popup.html", "type": "popup"}, function(wd){
     console.log(wd);
     wd.document.getElementById("txtField").value = "asd";
  })
});
```

**popup.html**

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
        <input type="text" id="txtField" />
   </body>
</html>
```

When I run this code, it says "Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined".

Comment: what's the result of the `console.log` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Extension - Get DOM content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758028/chrome-extension-get-dom-content)

Comment: I would suggest that you read the [Chrome extension architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch)  (and perhaps work through reading the pages linked from there). It has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done.

Comment: @Jean-maximeBouloc is a chrome window object, not a regular DOM window... https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#type-Window

Comment: @AndréDion I don't think it's the same question. He doesn't seem to know what is the function of background, popup or content scripts and I'm kind of used to it.

Comment: @Makyen I've already read it, but I couldn't find this answer, because chrome.window.create callback doesn't return a regular DOM object, but a chrome window object, and I'm not able to access the DOM. I may be wrong, 'cause I'm pretty new working with javascript and chrome extension.

Comment: @LucasMello, yeah. The info that you need is not clearly spelled out with respect to your exact situation. Generally, you will want to do DOM manipulations from within JavaScript loaded with a `<script>` tag within your *popup.html* just like you would for a browser action popup or options page.

Answer (score 2):

### Use JavaScript in a file included in the HTML with `<script>`

Generally, you should do DOM manipulations from within JavaScript loaded with a `<script>` tag within your *popup.html*, just like you would for a browser action popup or options page. For example from JavaScript in a *popup.js* file and included in *popup.html* like:

```html
<html>
   <head>
     <script src="popup.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
        <input type="text" id="txtField" />
   </body>
</html>
```

### Actually manipulating the DOM of the new window from the opener

If you are wanting to access the [Window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) of a popup, you will need to get a view for it using [`chrome.extension.getViews()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getViews). This is complicated by the fact that the window does not actually exist yet when the callback from `chrome.windows.create()` is executed, or when a `chrome.windows.onCreated` listener (or `windows.onFocusChanged`) is called (both fire before the `chrome.windows.create()` callback is executed). There does not appear to be an event which will notify you when the new popup window actually exists, or when you can get a view for it.

Thus, you are **much** better off using code in a JavaScript file which is included in the HTML using a `<script>` tag.

If you still desire to manipulate the DOM of the opened window, you are going to have to poll until you find a view for it. The following will do what you want:

*background.js*:

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.windows.create({"url": "popup.html", "type": "popup"}, function(wd){
        waitForWindowId(winObject.id,50,20,function(view){
            console.log(view);
            view.document.getElementById("txtField").value = "asd";
        });
    })
});

function waitForWindowId(id,delay,maxTries,callback) {
    let where = 'watchForWindow';
    if(maxTries--<=0){
        //Fail softly. You may want to do something else on failure to find the new window.
        return;
    }
    //This type of window is a type:'tab', not type:'popup'.
    if(!chrome.extension.getViews({windowId:id}).some(view=>{
        if(typeof callback === 'function'){
            callback(view);
        }
        return true;
    })){
        //Did not find the view for window ID. Keep trying
        setTimeout(waitForWindowId,delay,id,delay,maxTries,callback);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
chrome.windows.create(
    {
        url:'https://site.ru',
        type: 'popup',
        state: 'maximized',
    },
    function(window) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(window.tabs[0].id, {
            file: '/back/inject.js',
        });
    }
);
```