# How to paste text in <div> with chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I would like to paste some pre-defined text to a textbox of a website using chrome extension. The target website is https://www.urlgot.com/. It is a seemly simple webpage with only one input textbox. I had found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758028/chrome-extension-get-dom-content) to get my interesting DOM content. But how to manipulate the DOM to paste my text into the "placeholder" then? 
As a neophyte in chrome extension scripting, I really need some advice.

The DOM of interesting is as below,

```
<div class="form-group" id="urlFormGroup">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mediaWebUrl" autocomplete="off" placeholder="paste link here ..." onpaste="parse()">
```

I think I should find some way to replace the "paste link here ..." text with my own text input. But I don't know how to do it.
Thank you.

Comment: `document.getElementById('mediaWebUrl').setAttribute('placeholder','My own text...');`

Comment: @IvánNokonoko AAAmazing！ It works very well! It is a pity could not accept your comment as the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
document.getElementById('mediaWebUrl').setAttribute('placeholder','My own text...');
```