# How to make a "click" as I got the DOM of the button with chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I would like to make a mouse left click on a button in a website using chrome extension. The target website is https://www.urlgot.com/. It is a seemly simple webpage with only one button. I had found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758028/chrome-extension-get-dom-content) to get my interesting DOM content and how to [paste text into the textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56985016/how-to-paste-text-in-div-with-chrome-extension).Then how to make a click to the button? As a neophyte in chrome extension scripting, I really need some advice.

The DOM of interesting is as below,

```
<button type="button" class="button button-action button-circle button-raised" id="parseButton" onclick="parse()"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
```

I am confused with how to make the click. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do the job:

```
document.getElementById("parseButton").click();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Ashamed for my little knowledge of DOM manipulation command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to click

```
$('#parseButton').click()
```

or Javascript

```
document.getElementById('parseButton').click()
```