# document.getElementsByClassName() not returning full list of elements in a custom chrome extension, but works in chrome console

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I am trying to make a Chrome extension that automatically endorses all the skills of the person you are viewing on LinkedIn.

I have the basic extension from following the tutorial on google:

the manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "ALSE - Auto LinkedIn Skills Endorser",
  "description": "This extension allows you to automatically endorse all of the skills of the LinkedIn friend you are currently viewing with a single click!",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Click here to see the endorse all of the skills of your LinkedIn friend!"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
  ]
}
```

popup.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--
 This page is shown when the extension button is clicked, because the
 "browser_action" field in manifest.json contains the "default_popup" key with
 value "popup.html".
 -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans-serif;
        font-size: 100%;
      }
      #status {
        /* avoid an excessively wide status text */
        white-space: pre;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-width: 400px;
      }
    </style>

    <!--
      - JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files: see our Content Security
      - Policy documentation[1] for details and explanation.
      -
      - [1]: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy
     -->
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="status"></div>
    <img id="image-result" hidden>
    <button id ="testButton" type="button">Click Me!</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js:

```
// Copyright (c) 2014 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

/**
 * Get the current URL.
 *
 * @param {function(string)} callback - called when the URL of the current tab
 *   is found.
 */
function getCurrentTabUrl(callback) {
  // Query filter to be passed to chrome.tabs.query - see
  // https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query
  var queryInfo = {
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true
  };

  chrome.tabs.query(queryInfo, function(tabs) {
    // chrome.tabs.query invokes the callback with a list of tabs that match the
    // query. When the popup is opened, there is certainly a window and at least
    // one tab, so we can safely assume that |tabs| is a non-empty array.
    // A window can only have one active tab at a time, so the array consists of
    // exactly one tab.
    var tab = tabs[0];

    // A tab is a plain object that provides information about the tab.
    // See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab
    var url = tab.url;

    // tab.url is only available if the "activeTab" permission is declared.
    // If you want to see the URL of other tabs (e.g. after removing active:true
    // from |queryInfo|), then the "tabs" permission is required to see their
    // "url" properties.
    console.assert(typeof url == 'string', 'tab.url should be a string');

    callback(url);
  });

  // Most methods of the Chrome extension APIs are asynchronous. This means that
  // you CANNOT do something like this:
  //
  // var url;
  // chrome.tabs.query(queryInfo, function(tabs) {
  //   url = tabs[0].url;
  // });
  // alert(url); // Shows "undefined", because chrome.tabs.query is async.
}

/**
 * @param {string} searchTerm - Search term for Google Image search.
 * @param {function(string,number,number)} callback - Called when an image has
 *   been found. The callback gets the URL, width and height of the image.
 * @param {function(string)} errorCallback - Called when the image is not found.
 *   The callback gets a string that describes the failure reason.
 */
function getImageUrl(searchTerm, callback, errorCallback) {
  // Google image search - 100 searches per day.
  // https://developers.google.com/image-search/
  var searchUrl = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images' +
    '?v=1.0&q=' + encodeURIComponent(searchTerm);
  var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
  x.open('GET', searchUrl);
  // The Google image search API responds with JSON, so let Chrome parse it.
  x.responseType = 'json';
  x.onload = function() {
    // Parse and process the response from Google Image Search.
    var response = x.response;
    if (!response || !response.responseData || !response.responseData.results ||
        response.responseData.results.length === 0) {
      errorCallback('No response from Google Image search!');
      return;
    }
    var firstResult = response.responseData.results[0];
    // Take the thumbnail instead of the full image to get an approximately
    // consistent image size.
    var imageUrl = firstResult.tbUrl;
    var width = parseInt(firstResult.tbWidth);
    var height = parseInt(firstResult.tbHeight);
    console.assert(
        typeof imageUrl == 'string' && !isNaN(width) && !isNaN(height),
        'Unexpected respose from the Google Image Search API!');
    callback(imageUrl, width, height);
  };
  x.onerror = function() {
    errorCallback('Network error.');
  };
  x.send();
}

function renderStatus(statusText) {
  document.getElementById('status').textContent = statusText;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  getCurrentTabUrl(function(url) {
    // Put the image URL in Google search.
    renderStatus('Performing Google Image search for ' + url);

    getImageUrl(url, function(imageUrl, width, height) {

      renderStatus('Search term: ' + url + '\n' +
          'Google image search result: ' + imageUrl);
      var imageResult = document.getElementById('image-result');
      // Explicitly set the width/height to minimize the number of reflows. For
      // a single image, this does not matter, but if you're going to embed
      // multiple external images in your page, then the absence of width/height
      // attributes causes the popup to resize multiple times.
      imageResult.width = width;
      imageResult.height = height;
      imageResult.src = imageUrl;
      imageResult.hidden = false;

    }, function(errorMessage) {
      renderStatus('Cannot display image. ' + errorMessage);
    });
  });
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var button = document.getElementById('testButton');
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("endorse-button");
    // onClick's logic below:
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert(elems);
        alert(elems.length);
        for (i in elems) {
            elems[i].click()
        }
    });
});
```

When I am on a LinkedIn profile of a friend, I am able to endorse their skills using the following command in the Chrome console:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("endorse-button")[0].click();
```

where 0 can be replaced by any integer

The main problem I am having is, when I try to put this logic in the Chrome extension, it doesn't work. I always get that elems.length is 0, where

```
elems = document.getElementsByClassName("endorse-button");
```

This is the code snippet from popup.js that has the logic:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var button = document.getElementById('testButton');
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("endorse-button");
    // onClick's logic below:
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert(elems);
        alert(elems.length);
        for (i in elems) {
            elems[i].click()
        }
    });
});
```

I think this has to do with background.js? And the background attribute in the manifest? Not sure, I will continue to tinker and keep you posted. This should be easy to figure out. Thank you!!!

Comment: read about dinamic pages that load content afterwards with ajax. also seems like a bad idea to blindly endorse all skills.

Comment: hmm when I just try to do document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var button = document.getElementById('testButton');
 // onClick's logic below:
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("endorse-button")[0].click();
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("endorse-button");
  alert(elems);
  alert(elems.length);
  for (i in elems) {
   elems[i].click()
  }
    });
}); I got a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined while debugging the chrome extension

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964225/accessing-current-tab-dom-object-from-popup-html

Comment: thank you so much, Zig Mandel and myf, will try my best !!

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! This link solved it !!! https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-make-a-chrome-extension It works now!!! Woo Hoo!!!

Comment: You can add it to your chrome browser too! ALSE - Auto LinkedIn Skills Endorser !! https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/alse-auto-linkedin-skills/biplppgfagljlnclhllmjanphpcogomd