# How to store DOM as HTML file in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, web, browser

Suppose I have an HTML, which contains only the URL of a javascript library which builds the actual DOM. So the browser:

- loads that HTML
- loads and executes the javascript code, which creates the actual DOM
- renders the DOM

Now I (as a browser user) want to store that DOM as HTML file. How can I do it with Chrome ?

Comment: There is an topic about this with useful information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964225/accessing-current-tab-dom-object-from-popup-html

Comment: There is a topic about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964225/accessing-current-tab-dom-object-from-popup-html Thanks!

Comment: Did you get a good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just Ctrl+S on the webpage to save the HTML. JavaScript cannot access the file system for security purposes.

Comment: Thanks. I am afraid this is not what I exactly need. This is the HTML  the browser loaded but not the DOM created by the code.

Comment: @Michael - You could try using the Inspector Tool  (F12), go to the Elements tab, right click on the <html> tag in your code and select 'Copy as HTML'. Then paste that into a new file and save. Also try just 'Copy' instead of 'Copy as HTML' if the latter doesn't suite your needs.

Comment: Thanks again. I will try it.